# cin.getline() in for loop is killing me

Tags: c++, cin

I am practicing how to use `cin` nowadays. And I tried to use `cin.getline()` in for loop to get consecutive inputs. What I tried to do was:

1. Using `cin`, get integer NUM and LEN.
2. Using `cin` in for loop, get NUM lines with not more than LEN characters.

And I tried to code like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    char arr[100][100];
    int i, j;
    int NUM, LEN;

    cout << "Input the NUM: " << endl;
    cin >> NUM;

    cout << "Input the LEN: " << endl;
    cin >> LEN;

    cout << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        cin.getline(arr[i],LEN+1);

    }

    cout << "Your Input: ";
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        cout << "row" << i << " :: " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Frankly, this works quite nicely if I input only valid values... But when I just input more characters than LEN in some lines, it really mess up.

I tried really many things... such as `cin.clear()`, `cin.ignore(limit of buffer header <limits> say, '\n')`, `fflush(stdin)` and so on... I think if there's any alternatives of `fflush(stdin)` in C, it would work...

I just want to get only first LEN characters for each line and discard other extra input. How can I flush the whole buffer?

Comment: Hi why do not you do cin.getline() and read everything and then chop off every char right of LEN ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
int main(void){

    char arr[100][100];
    int i, j;
    int NUM, LEN;

    cout << "Input the NUM: " << endl;
    cin >> NUM;

    cout << "Input the LEN: " << endl;
    cin >> LEN;

    cout << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    char temp[100];
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        cin.getline(temp,100);
        strncpy(arr[i],temp,LEN);
        arr[i][LEN]= 0;
    }

    cout << "Your Input: ";
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        cout << "row" << i << " :: " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT! You are really like an angel, and I didn't expect this quick response... I really appreciate it.

Comment: But may I ask you more?
1. I am still not sure how your answer works. Well... I used cin.getline() in my code, too, but extra characters in buffer messed it up. Did cin.getline() work fine in your code because you read 100 of characters? Though I love your way, but isn't there any way to just flush the buffer(so that extra characters are erased) after each cin.getline()?
2. What does arr[i][LEN] = 0; mean? Just to make sure it is the end of the string?

It is ridiculous to say, but even when I become a good programmer someday, how can I forget you :D

Comment: Hi again, I try to answer in order my version works because I read 100 chars? YES, more precisely it works because it tries to read as many characters as possible and reads all chars typed by the user, but if a user types in 101 characters we would have the bug again. I do not know if it is possible to flush all characters exceeding the fixed limit direclty from cin but if you find out I would be glad to know.

Comment: finally arr[i][LEN]=0 is necessary because otherwise the data can be dirty, cin.getline() puts the 0 at the end of the array of received character but as we go and delete excediing data from the received chars we end up deleting also the 0 that was put there by getline() so we have to put the 0 again.